# Protege: How to express an axiom stating that class A is related to class B that has data value X?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I'm trying to express an axiom of the following kind:

"Water has some physical quantity called melting temperature, which has a value of 100.0"

I've tried definig the following class expression:

```
Water SubClassOf (hasPhysicalQuality some (MeltingTemperature and hasValue value 100.0f))
```

And I have the following assertions:

```
Water               Type                 owl:Class
hasPhysicalQuality  Type                 owl:ObjectProperty
hasValue            Type                 owl:DataProperty

this_water          Type                 Water
this_temperature    Type                 MeltingTemperature
this_water          hasPhysicalQuality   this_temperature
this_temperature    hasValue             50.0f
```

When I ran the Pellet reasoner, I was expecting to find inconsistency since the melting temperature (this_temperature) related to this_water has a value of 50.0f, not 100.0f. However, the reasoner did not indicate any inconsistency.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: The correct axioms required were:

```
Water SubClassOf (hasPhysicalQuantity exactly 1 MeltingTemperature)
Water SubClassOf (hasPhysicalQuanlity some (MeltingTemperature and (hasValue value 100.0f)
hasValue Type owl:FunctionalProperty
```

Comment: I figured it out. The expression should have been:
Water SubClassOf (hasPhysicalQuality only (MeltingTemperature and hasValue value 100.0f))

Comment: To your comment: what if `this_water` has also `BoilingTemperature`?

Comment: That's true...my solution only resolves the case when it has one physical quantity. It'd be great if someone else suggested a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your data property functional - or, as you say in the comments, apply a cardinality restriction.

Comment: I needed to make the data property function AND put a cardinality restriction on the object property for each specific property.